# pthread with callback to python VM

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, ctypes, pthreads

Let's say I have a python script which loads a shared library (SL) through ctypes.

- The SL sets up a `pthread` T1
- The python script configures callbacks through the SL i.e. python script calls functions from the SL with references to python callables

[alt text http://www.gliffy.com/pubdoc/1993061/L.jpg](http://www.gliffy.com/pubdoc/1993061/L.jpg)

Now, let's say T1 calls a "callback" function, are the following assumptions true:

- the callback function on the Python side is executed within the context of T1
- I can use a **[queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html)** to communicate between T1 and the Python VM
- I would need to poll the said `queue` on the Python VM side

I understand all the concepts of threading, shared state etc. but I haven't dug very deep on the multi-threading side with Python.  Since there is an adaptation layer which I do not know enough at the moment (ctypes), I am afraid I'll be missing some key aspects of the process.

Comment: @jldupont, one critical item for ctypes callbacks: stash a reference to the callback that will last at least as long as the C code will need its own reference, or you'll get a crash.  This is now noted in the docs under "Important note for callback functions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling the queue isn't normally necessary (you can devote another thread on the Python side to doing blocking `.get` calls on it), but that's not a big deal.  Problem is, with such an arrangement, you might get caught by the [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) -- see the three links from this wikipedia page for ample treatments thereof.

When you interface to/from C with C (or [Cython](http://www.cython.org/)) code using the Python C API, you can release and acquire the GIL pretty simply, at least, hopefully avoiding deadlocks and the like; with ctypes, GIL operations are automated in callback to/from C situations, so if there's any other lock in play a deadlock is a risk (since things are not within your control you can't easily ensure Djikstra's **[Banker Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker's_algorithm)** is applied).

Comment: +1: If I understand you correctly, `ctypes` introduces a `thunk` which handles locking/unlocking the GIL to/from the Cython interpreter, right? In other words, the callback python function would effectively executes within the Cython VM, right?

Comment: @jldupont, Cython doesn't introduce another VM of its own -- rather, it generates C code which (depending on what it's doing) runs on the bare metal or makes calls to the Python VM, just like C code you could write by hand according to Python's C API.  `ctypes` is different and does introduce thunks for callbacks to take care of the GIL (convenient, but you get less control).  Python functions always execute in the Python VM, and thus need to be holding the GIL while they execute.

Comment: `thunking` there is, I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily implemented with Cython . I have written a sample at 
https://github.com/sachinpc/cython/tree/master/Demos/mt_callback

The example shows how to wrap python callback in cython, when being called from a pthread. For your specific use-case , you could add to a Queue or dequeue object in the thread code from the callback function . In the sameple , I have added  prints for both pthread-id and python-thread-id in the extension .